# Different division result python

Tags: python, python-3.x, division

I have some strange result in my python 3.6.3. Once i tried some code and i reach this problem.

```
>>> a = 10**32
>>> print(a/1000/1000)
9.999999999999999e+25
```

As you see it not actually right, but if i go other way, i reach what i expect

```
>>> print(a/1000000)
1e+26
```

Same thing with

```
>>> 10**26
>>> 10**31
```

Can somebody explain me what's wrong? i tried write it in one line no result

Comment: try integer division `a//1000//1000`, you'll get `100000000000000000000000000`

Comment: integer division works cleary right, but why double division by 1000 and division by 10**6 have different results

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = 10**32
>>> a/1000/1000
9.999999999999999e+25
```

As you know, Python 3 division is no longer an integer division (`a//1000//1000` would have worked fine), so you're performing 2 floating point divisions here, introducing an (unnecessary) floating point accumulation error.

```
>>> a/1000000
1e+26
```

this only performs *one* division, so lower floating point error effect, even if result is now floating point.

Comment: Thanks. Now i understand this principe of floating point operation.